# Search then echo file name with results from grep PHP command

Tags: php, html, forms, grep, echo

I'm trying to make it so my PHP script will not only just echo the search results that I put in, but also list the .txt file's name ontop of the search results.

Here is how my system currently works:
I input whatever term, let's say *example* then the search is processed through my PHP script and then echoed on the script's page.
The search can be whatever, from symbols to any word that might be in the txt files within my folder that the script is checking.

Here's my HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="search.php" class="search" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
       <input type="text" name="query" maxlength=75 class="searchbox" minlength=3 placeholder="enter data" required>
       <input type="submit" value="Search"></input>
</form>
```

Here's my PHP script: (search.php)

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
system('grep -hir ' . escapeshellarg($_POST['query']) . ' *folder/*.txt');
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Here's an example of a .txt file in /folder/ directory with the lines being listed: (keep in mind there are multiple txt files with different messages, and any of the files include special and normal characters in them)

```
example message
search results
test1
test2305
results
```

How can I go about doing this? I looked up checking file name and I tried a bunch of methods but couldn't find something that worked.

Comment: `-h` tells `grep` not to show the filenames. Use `-H` to force it to show the filenames.

Comment: On a side note: It is **never** a good idea to allow user data into your systems shell environment. There is **always** a more secure way.

Comment: @Barmar I switched it to -H but is there a way I can have it not show the directory with it, just the file name?

Comment: @NicholasSummers For now this is a private project just for me but what would be a better way to do this? I'm not experienced in MySQL otherwise I would have probably made it for that instead.

Comment: @Moses MySQL is a minor but necessary evil, I would highly suggest becoming familiar with it. Especially understanding how it stores data types. In this case it looks like you are attempting to manage and search text files, which MySQL is very good at. Finally, regardless if you plan on making your code public or not, you should always develop you code as if it will be publicly displayed and scrutinized. That will keep you developing bad habits and will prevent you from ever having to refactor your code should it ever become public.

Comment: @NicholasSummers Thank you for the reasoning behind this, I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @moses No problem, and good luck!

Comment: @Moses If none of the filenames contain `:`, you can pipe the grep output through `sed 's#[^:]*/([^:]*\)#\1#'`

Comment: @Barmar The files contain all special and normal characters. I tried -H instead of what I had but it listed the directory /example/ then the file name example.txt: in a string that looks like this: example/example.txt:searcheditem394 for every string that was echoed back it did this as it should have but I'm trying to make it so if it finds those it wont do it for every line, it will be organized and will list the file name ontop, and all of the matching contents below it until the next file is listed and so on. How can I go about this?

Comment: You'll need to write code that parses the output, extracting the filename before `:`, and seeing if it's the same as the previous line so you don't repeat the filename. You can use the PHP `basename()` function to remove the directory portion, instead of `sed`.

Comment: @Barmar Alright, thank you. I'll give it a try.